# jquery: how do i know if i have it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i need jquery to work on a browser locally. how do i know if it is installed and how do i install it ?

my question is specific to being able to run this code:

```
onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '0.5'); $('#someDiv').show();"
onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '1'); $('#someDiv').hide();"
```

Comment: Don't use onmouseover="" with jQuery. Use jQuery-style event binding, like:
$('#sourceDiv').mouseover(function() {}); See the jQuery tutorials: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me:_Using_selectors_and_events

Comment: sorry what shoul di use then can u giev me an xeample

Comment: Answering the first part of your question, you can test if jquery is loaded with: `if(jQuery) alert('jQuery is loaded');`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are going to include jQuery locally, as per Robert's suggestion, you will first have to download it from here: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js

Answer (score 16):

You can test if jQuery is loaded by opening your javascript console (in Chrome: Settings > More tools > Javascript console).

Where the little blue arrow appears type:

```
if(jQuery) alert('jQuery is loaded');
```

Press enter.

Answer (score 5):

jQuery isn't installed like a program, it's a file that needs to be included in your source code somehow, the most common practice is to include by adding `<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript' src='local/path/to/jquery.js'></script>` in the `<head>` section of your page.

Comment: or put it above your closing `body` tag if you want the page to load more quickly

Answer (score 3):

put this right above your closing `body` tag:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/[jquery version here]/jquery.min.js"
language="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

jquery isn't "installed" into a browser. it's a js library referenced from the web page you are viewing.

**EDIT:** This works if you have internet access. If not, you will have to download that file to your local system and reference the local path.

Comment: @I__ then you are doing it wrong. like i said, include that line if you have internet access. if not, you must download the jquery file, save it locally, then reference it in the script tag.