# what does #someDiv mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xml

When the user puts his mouseover this object `i` want a message to pop up:

```
onmouseover="
    evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '0.5'); 
    $('#someDiv').show();" 
onmouseout="
    evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','1)');
    $('#someDiv').hide();"
```

What exaclty does `someDIv` mean? Where do I put the text?

I am doing this and it is not showing the text at all. It is just changing the opacity.

```
<path 
    d="M 242.96145,653.59282 L 244.83646,650.1553 
       L 247.02397,649.8428 L 247.33647,650.62405 
       L 245.30521,653.59282 L 242.96145,653.59282 
       z M 252.80525,649.99905 L 258.74278,652.49906 
       L 260.77404,652.18656 L 262.33654,648.43654 
       L 261.71154,645.15528 L 257.64902,644.68653 
       L 253.74275,646.40528 L 252.80525,649.99905 
       z M 282.49289,659.6866 L 286.08665,664.99912 
       L 288.43041,664.68662 L 289.52417,664.21787 
       L 290.93042,665.46787 L 294.52419,665.31162 
       L 295.4617,663.90537 L 292.64918,662.18661 
       L 290.77417,658.59284 L 288.74291,655.15533 
       L 283.11789,657.96784 L 282.49289,659.6866 
       z M 302.02423,668.28039 L 303.27423,666.40538 
       L 307.8055,667.34288 L 308.43051,666.87413 
       L 314.36803,667.49913 L 314.05553,668.74914 
       L 311.55552,670.15539 L 307.33675,669.84289 
       L 302.02423,668.28039 z M 307.1805,673.28041 
       L 309.05551,677.03043 L 312.02427,675.93667 
       L 312.33677,674.37416 L 310.77427,672.3429 
       L 307.1805,672.0304 L 307.1805,673.28041 
       z M 313.89928,672.18665 L 316.08679,669.37414 
       L 320.61806,671.7179 L 324.83683,672.81166 
       L 329.0556,675.46792 L 329.0556,677.34293 
       L 325.61809,679.06169 L 320.93056,679.99919 
       L 318.5868,678.59293 L 313.89928,672.18665 
       z M 329.99311,687.18672 L 331.55561,685.93672 
       L 334.83688,687.49923 L 342.18066,690.93674 
       L 345.46193,692.968 L 347.02443,695.31176 
       L 348.89944,699.53053 L 352.80571,702.03054 
       L 352.49321,703.28055 L 348.74319,706.40556 
       L 344.68067,707.81182 L 343.27442,707.18682 
       L 340.30565,708.90557 L 337.96189,712.03059 
       L 335.77438,714.8431 L 334.05562,714.68685 
       L 330.61811,712.18684 L 330.30561,707.81182 
       L 330.93061,705.46806 L 329.3681,699.99928 
       L 327.33684,698.28052 L 327.18059,695.78051 
       L 329.3681,694.84301 L 331.39936,691.87425 
       L 331.86811,690.93674 L 330.30561,689.21798 
       L 329.99311,687.18672 z"
    id="HI"
   style="fill:#ffffd0" 
   onmouseover="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity', '0.5'); $('#id').show();"
   onmouseout="evt.target.setAttribute('opacity','1)'); $('#id').hide();" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561695/jquery-how-do-i-know-if-i-have-it

Comment: Are posting a new question for every bit of code you read/don't understand? It seems like you've been posting a new one every ten minutes. You should take some time, try to understand what you're dealing with, and try to decipher things on your own.

Comment: `$('#someDiv')` gets `<div id="someDiv">`. In jquery, if you want to do something with a `<div>`, like showing it, hiding it, ... you use the id-selector.

Comment: Others think this is not worth an answer too. SO is not like chat where what you ask is gone minutes latter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'#someDiv' is a <s>CSS3</s>CSS selector which is semantically equivalent to `getElementById('someDiv')`, in that it will select the element with ID 'someDiv'. So:

```js
document.getElementById('someDiv')
```

==

```js
// bracket notation will return a DOM element
$("#someDiv")[0]

// leaving it out will return a jQuery object
$("#someDiv")
```

Comment: karim thank youi very much but "can you just help me make this work"

Comment: `#someDiv` isn't CSS3 selector - it's much older... ;)

Comment: @Crozin - How far back does it go?

Comment: it's existed since CSS was introduced.

Answer (score 1):

`someDiv` is simply the ID associated to an element.

Comment: im very very sorry to ask but how do i make some text appear?a

Answer (score 1):

Like karim79 and others said, #someDiv selects an element with an id of "someDiv" So, to get this to work, you will also need to place an element somewhere in your HTML with this ID. Something like

```
<p id="someDiv">Your message</p>
```

Comment: great, where shoul dit be placed exactly/?

Comment: It really doesn't matter just so long as it's somewhere in the <body> element. It sounds like you might be trying to make something like a tooltip, so you may want to look at jQuery tooltip examples, like these: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/resources/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Comment: The reason I say the above is because if you want the #someDiv element to appear and hide on the mouse event, then that's relatively simple. If you want it to appear in a specific place like, say, at the mouse location, that's a bit more involved.

Answer (score 0):

`#someDiv` is just a item with `"someDiv"` as ID (that's right on CSS or Javascript).

In this case, you are ""loading"" `#somediv` and then, showing it (using jquery) or hiding it (with mouse in or mouse out)

Comment: im very very sorry to ask but how do i make some text appear?a

Comment: You put the text inside of the div tags, so it would probably look like (in your HTML):

<div id="someDiv">Hover Text Here</div>

Answer (score 0):

`#someDiv` is the id of the element (div I believe) which you want to show.  You would put your text or whatever you want to show in the element with id='someDiv'

Comment: im very very sorry to ask but how do i make some text appear?a